# Select value from combobox for datasource to query database

Tags: asp.net, combobox, asp.net-ajax, datasource, mschart

I've generated a graph using the Chart function in ASP.NET which retrieves its data from an SQL database. At the moment it retrieves all the Temperatures for 2008 since I've asked the SQL datasource to find all dates that include 2008. I have been trying to connect a combo box to the SQL datasource so when i select a year, it looks for that specific year rather than 2008. The below code currently works without the combo box and retrieves all Temps for 2008:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        Height="349px" Width="977px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="JobDate" YValueMembers="CureTemp">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:T2DataString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T2] WHERE DatePart(yyyy, JobDate) = 2008">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I then added the following combo box and changed my SQL datasource as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:T2DataString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T2] WHERE ([JobDate] = @JobDate)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ComboBox" DbType="Date" Name="JobDate" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ComboBox" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2010</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2009</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2008</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

When i attempt to run the application it says: 'String was not recognised as a valid DateTime'. How do i convert the value in the combo box to an integer so it can be used in the datasource? I'm not trying to populate a drop down menu with data from a datasource, I'm trying to use the drop down menu to enter a value in the datasource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your dropdown listitems to `<asp:ListItem Value="2011">2011</asp:ListItem>` and also your sql query should be similar to your query from first code snippet `DatePart(yyyy, JobDate)`

Comment: Hello. Ive tried what you suggested and i get an error when i try and run the page: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Thanks

Comment: change `DbType="Date"` to `DbType="String"` in sqldatasource